# Live reload Prometheus configuration in docker(-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I have a new server running Prometheus in docker-compose. 
I want to be able to re-load the configuration file (prometheus.yml) without have to stop and start the container.

Of course since I persist the storage of promethues in a volume the stop and start isn't really a problem but it seems like overkill, especially since prometheus itself has such a handy api to reload configs.

I see other people with similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46044324/docker-not-propagating-file-changes-from-host-to-container)) but I have been unable to get those solutions to work for me. Maybe I'm overlooking something there.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:

  grafana:
    restart: always
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:6.2.1
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - grafanadata:/var/lib/grafana

  prometheus:
    restart: always
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.10.0
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./configuration/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheusdata:/prometheus

    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--web.enable-admin-api'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  node:
    restart: always
    container_name: node
    image: prom/node-exporter:v0.18.0
    ports:
      - 9100:9100

volumes:
  grafanadata:
  prometheusdata:
```

**Alas, my results..**

When I run `curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/-/reload` the docker-compose logs give:

```
prometheus    | level=info ts=2019-06-17T15:33:02.690Z caller=main.go:730 msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus    | level=info ts=2019-06-17T15:33:02.691Z caller=main.go:758 msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

So the prometheus' end is working fine.. All good so far.

However, when I edit `./configuration/prometheus/prometheus.yml` the changes don't propogate to the container. 
Furthermore, when I try to edit `/etc/promethus/prometheus.yml` in container I see that it is read only (and as an aside, the container does not have a 'sudo' command).

Is there a docker native way to hot/live reload these config files to the container directory?

As stated, the down/start option works for now but I'm curious if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might be, that your editor is not saving the changed file under the same inode. So dockerd does not realize that the file changed, since its written to a new inode.
Solutions might be to mount the complete directory or tell your editor to not use a temporary file:

I.e. for Sublime, setting "atomic_save": false to user preferences might help (results unclear) or for vim see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793#issuecomment-571932545

This issue is very interesting for this topic in general: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15793

Comment: Enlightening! Thank you for posting on this old-ish post. It may be some months until I get the opportunity to revisit this, but I will update here once I do.

Answer (score 11):

`docker-compose kill -s SIGHUP prometheus` does the trick, so Vishrant was certainly on to something there.

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you have already updated the `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` file and you are just asking about the reloading of config. (Though the config can be part of `configmap`, and you can avoid the pod restart when the `configmap` changes).

Run the following command in order to reload the config without stopping the prometheus process:

```
docker exec <prometheus_container_name> sudo killall -HUP prometheus
```

Explanation: `sudo killall -HUP prometheus` command sends a `SIGHUP` signal to the prometheus process to reload the configurations.

Validate the changes by calling:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9090/api/v1/status/config
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a slightly different docker-compose.yml file. I use the following script to reload prometheus:

```
#!/bin/bash

promtool='docker-compose exec prometheus promtool'

error_found=0

${promtool} check config /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml || error_found=1

# See mapping in docker-compose
# ./config/:/config/ allow us a local lookup and remote check
# of rules files
for rules_file in ./config/alerts/*yml
do
    ${promtool} check rules "/${rules_file}" || error_found=1
done

if [[ ${error_found} -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Not reloading config, errors found."
else
    docker-compose kill -s SIGHUP prometheus
fi
```

It will check the config and rules files first. If they are fine prometheus will be triggered to reload.

Comment: Users don't seem to even read answers before upvoting.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like

```
      - ./configuration/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

should be reversed.